# Google Sheets QUERY special sort order by string format

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to sort the values of a QUERY in Google Sheets by a special string format, without using any helper columns and any other additional helper columns.

So only values with the format "12345-12345" should sorted to the beginning ot the end.

ChatGTP and Google Bards responded with this solution:

`=QUERY(A:B, "SELECT * ORDER BY B, B LIKE '#####-#####'")`

**But I think the QUERY function in Google Sheets are limited to standard orders like by alphabet or numbers and doesn't offers any special sort orders.**

Comment: Do you want the unsorted values which are not like '12345-12345' to come before or after the sorted '12345-12345' values?

Comment: The unsorted values should appear before the '12345-12345" values. The '12345-12345' values should be always the  last shown values at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to exactly answer because we can't see your data, however the easiest way of achieving your desired result is to split the QUERY in two where the 1st QUERY returns all the non '12345-12345' rows, the 2nd returns only the '12345-12345' rows, and then stack the two ranges using array literals.

Your 1st QUERY will therefore need to contain a `where not X matches '\d{5}-\d{5}'` to exclude the relevant rows, and the 2nd will need to contain `where X matches '\d{5}-\d{5}'`. Stack the two ranges using `={query1;query2}`. If your query has headers it's a little more complex as they'll need to be removed from the second query.

Please provide some example data if this isn't clear, and I'll elaborate.